# removing invisible header from ipad tableview

Tags: ipad, header, tableview

my UITableView has some kind of invisible header / inset on iPad and not on iPhone.

[image: iphone tableView]
[image: ipad tableView]

I tried all the following to remove this unwanted header/inset, with no success:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableview.sectionHeaderHeight = 0.f;
    self.tableview.sectionFooterHeight = 0.f;
    self.tableview.tableHeaderView = nil;
    self.tableview.tableFooterView = nil;
    self.tableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.f;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.f;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"";
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull] autorelease];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a way...

```
self.tableview.tableHeaderView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, FLT_MIN)] autorelease];
```

You can't use: `nil`, `CGRectNull`, `CGRectZero`, or anything with a height of `0.f`. So I used `FLT_MIN` to be as close to `0.f` as possible.

Comment: For some weird reason, `CGRectZero` doesn't work, but this does! Nice find.